replace all char of given string by a given pattern with sed
I have many files with lines like:
[random strings] /a/given/path [random strings]
I would like to replace the /a/given/path by a pattern like XXXXXXXXXXXXX, the number of X being the size of the /a/given/path.
Say [random strings] does not contain the text to be matched (there is only a single occurrence of the searched string in the file)
I know how to replace it by a single X using sed 's|/a/given/path|X|g' but I don't get how to get the correct number of X depending on the input path length.
Ideally, I would rely on a single sed command, no scripting around, (but may be a acceptable fall back if not feasible with a single sed)

Can you show us a snippet of the file?

actually [random strings] /a/given/path [random strings] is a correct snippet as the important part is begin able to replace /a/given/path.

What exactly works also depends on whether [random strings] is completely static text (like your examples lead us to believe) or needs to be matched with a regular expression as well.

@tripleee say [random strings] does not contain the text to be matched (there is only a single occurence of the searched string in the file)

These details need to be included in the question itself (not as a comment, a link to an external page, an image, or etc).

If /a/given/path is (as its name suggests) given, then you know its length is 13 characters and you can just use XXXXXXXXXXXXX as the replacement.  Is that path actually not a fixed string?

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E ':a;\#/a/given/path#{s//\n&\n/;:b;s/^([^\n]*)\n[^\n]/\1X\n/;tb;s/\n//g;ba}' file

Erect some scaffolding around the /a/given/path, in this case newlines.
Replace every character between the scaffolding with X's.
Remove the scaffolding i.e. the newlines.
In more depth:
Find /a/given/path and surround that string with newlines (newlines are used since they cannot appear naturally as sed is line based).
Using iteration and substitution replace each character between the newlines with X.
Remove the newlines and go again.
N.B. The usual search regexp uses the / delimiter but in this case because we know the target includes this character an alternative is used instead \#...# i.e. the hash character.

looks like it works! could you try to explain what is going on so that I can feel like I learnt something? thank you

I would use awk for this.
Given file:
[random strings] /tmp/dir/foo [random strings]
[random strings] /tmp/dir/foobar [random strings]
[random strings] /tmp/dir/foobarbaz [random strings]

assuming you only have one path in the string you can use:
awk '
{
    match($0,/\/.+\/.+\/[^ ]+/); 
    s=sprintf("%*s",RLENGTH,""); 
    gsub(".","X",s); 
    gsub(/\/.+\/.+\/[^ ]+/,s,$0); 
    print $0
}' file

outputs:
[random strings] XXXXXXXXXXXX [random strings]
[random strings] XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [random strings]
[random strings] XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [random strings]


While it's probably possible to solve this with sed, I would strongly advise against trying. sed does not have the concept of a length, or a number, though with clever coding you could (say) replace every character in the string you want to replace with an X. But again, I would not go there; these types of sed scripts tend to be write-only.
Here's a simple Perl implementation.
perl -pe 's/(\[random strings\] )(.*?)( \[random strings\])/
     sprintf("%s%s%s", $1, "X" x length($2), $3) /ge' inputfile

If, as indicated in the question, you really don't care about the surrounding strings, and there is only one match per line, you don't need the complex back references or the /g flag:
perl -pe 's%(/a/given/path)% "X" x length($1) %e' inputfile

(This also illustrates how you can use an alternate delimiter instead of / if you like, which makes sense if your regex contains literal slashes, just like in sed.)
The e flag lets you use arbitrary Perl code in the replacement, not just static text with backreferences.
If you want to use the -i option to replace the input file in-place, Perl can do that too (whereas Awk out of the box cannot, though GNU Awk has the -i inplace extension).

This is much clearer and simpler in awk than sed, e.g. using GNU awk for multi-char RS, RT, and gensub():
$ awk -v RS='/a/given/path' -v ORS= '{print $0 gensub(/./,"X","g",RT)}' file
[random strings] XXXXXXXXXXXXX [random strings]

or using any awk assuming at most 1 matching string per input line (the OP said just 1 match across the whole of the input):
$ awk 'match($0,"/a/given/path") { tgt=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); gsub(/./,"X",tgt); $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) tgt substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)} 1' file
[random strings] XXXXXXXXXXXXX [random strings]

